# HomeBrew Install Thrift 404 Error

Tags: homebrew, thrift, osx-mavericks

Typing `brew install thrift` in Mac terminal attempts to download and install thrift-0.9.0 from following URLs:

```
==> Downloading http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=thrift/0.9.0/thrift-0.9.0.tar.gz
==> Best Mirror http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache/thrift/0.9.0/thrift-0.9.0.tar.gz
```

However I get a 404 Not Found Error.

Newest version of thrift is 0.9.1, but the `brew install thrift` command only tries to install 0.9.0.

How do I install Thrift using `brew install`?

Is this something being updated in home brew as I type? or do I need a different command?
Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.thrift.user/3389 and https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/25308 If you still have questions, please ask again on the Apache Thrift mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

For me a simple `brew update` did the job.

- But there seems to be issues presently with osx 10.9, I'm on 10.8

Answer (score 0):

brew edit thrift

```
#url 'http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=thrift/0.9.0/thrift-0.9.0.tar.gz'
url 'file:///path/to/thrift-0.9.0.tar.gz'
```